# How to implement search in recyclerview list in android that have pagination using firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity to show a list of data from the firebase realtime database. The activity have a search bar at the top and I want to filter the recyclerview based on the search text. The recyclerview has pagination.

Comment: share some code that you tried already.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I don't know what method to try, if I try with a local filter then I won't get the latest data due to pagination.

Answer (score 0):

if you want search in all pages you must define search class in server side and communicate with android side , for each character you must send request to server and get response , but if you want search in current RecyclerView you can simply use adapter that implements Filterable

Comment: In this case i think backend should handle search because pagination will work this way. If developer applies local filter then pagination will not work correctly.

Comment: pagination and search are different things , and i don't know fire base how handle this , but my answer is correct

Comment: I know they are different things. But can you tell me how can you paginate with local filter (filter in client side) ?

Comment: this is your smurf account ? please come with your account which write this question and i will answer

Comment: I just trying to tell if you filter your recyclerview locally then you will request new data because after filtering your item size probably will be smaller. And last item in your list wont be your actual last item because of filter. So you always had to be aware of this situation and its a little complicated. But if your backend filters data for you then you should not worry about correct last item to paginate.

Comment: yes , so ?  you just explain my answer in different way :)

Comment: Yes :) Just tried to tell why backendside is better.